# How to change the behavior of the function based on class constraints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type that represents a collection of values paired with a probability. At first, the implementation was just to use good old lists, but as you can imagine, this can be inefficient (for example, I use a Tree instead of a list to store ordered values)

After some research, I thought about using GADTs

```hs
data Tree a b = Leaf | Node {left::Tree a b, val :: (a, b), right :: Tree a b}

data Prob a where
  POrd   ::Ord a => Tree a Rational -> Prob a
  PEq    ::Eq a => [(a, Rational)] -> Prob a
  PPlain ::[(a, Rational)] -> Prob a
```

So far, so good. I'm now stuck at trying to create a smart constructor for my new data type,
that takes `[(a,Rational)]` and depending on the constraints of `a`, chooses the correct constructor for `Prob`. Basically:

```hs
prob :: [(a, Rational)] -> Prob a
-- chooses the "best" constructor based on the constraints of a
```

Is this at all possible? If not, how should I go about designing something better? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t make specialized smart constructors for the types you’d use `Prob` for? Like `pInt = POrd :: Tree Int Rational -> Prob Int`. I don’t see there being much utility to picking the right constructor for a given data type. It doesn’t save a user that much code or time. That said, this is still an interesting question. Just wanted to offer this comment in case you thought the `prob` function was necessary.

Comment: There isn't actually any requirement here, I'm just playing around with the type system and seeing what's possible. I'm basically trying to write a module, define its interface and use it afterwards pretending I don't know anything about the implementation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to perform a check of the form "is type `T` in class `C`?" in Haskell. The issue here is that it is hard to answer negatively to such question *and* allow separate compilation: `T` could be in `C` in the scope of one module but not in the scope of another one, causing a rather fragile semantics.

To ensure consistency, Haskell only allows to *require* a constraint, and raise an compile time error otherwise.

As far as I can see, the best you can do is to use another custom type class, which tells you which case is the best one. E.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data BestConstraint a where
   BCOrd  :: Ord a => BestConstraint a
   BCEq   :: Eq a => BestConstraint a
   BCNone :: BestConstraint a

class BC a where
   bestC :: BestConstraint a

instance BC Int where bestC = BCOrd
-- ... etc.
instance BC a => BC [a] where
   bestC = case bestC @a of
       BCOrd  -> BCOrd
       BCEq   -> BCEq
       BCNone -> BCNone

prob :: forall a . BestConstraint a => [(a, Rational)] -> Prob a
prob xs = case bestC @a of
    BCOrd  -> POrd ....  -- build the tree
    BCEq   -> PEq xs
    BCNone -> PPlain xs
```

You will have to provide an instance for any type you want to use, though.

Comment: I absolutely agree that this is the proper way to do it, however it should still be _mentioned_ that overlapping instances do provide a way to kind of decide based on whether or not an instance exists.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, how's that? Don't they just let you decide based on inequality?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote “kind of”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't think they can solve this specific problem, though. Can they?

Comment: @chi thanks a lot, that is definitely helpful. That is still somewhat a bit tedious for what I'm trying to do, I don't want to reason about concrete types, I want to abstract from them as much as possible.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think that might help me find it, I'm still struggling with the Documentation for it though

Comment: @chi what I mean is just, you could add `instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} BC a where` `bestC = BCNone` and then only the types that actually use `Ord`-optimisation would need to get instances; any other type would automatically be usable but without optimisation. Not saying this is a big advantage or even a good idea at all, but it does make a decision based on whether or not an (“explicit”) instance for a type exists – albeit not whether `Eq` and `Ord` exists, but whether `instance BC`  exists.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I now see your point. Essentially you provide a default fallback inefficient implementation, and then enable the optimization manually, on a case by case basis. You still need to list the optimized cases, but only those.